# Approval about edit requests

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

Why does SO sometimes asks for my approval on an edit of my post/answers and sometimes it doesn't?

Comment: From Über Meta: [No notification was received for an edit to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202359/no-notification-was-received-for-an-edit-to-a-post)

Comment: This is different, I get the notifications, but sometimes it ask for my approval on edits, sometimes it doesn't

Comment: Users with >= 2k reputation can edit posts directly, without review. You only need to "approve" edits that were made by users with less than 2k.

Comment: ah. ok.. I see.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit